# Testing Android Realm with RxJava - "opened from a thread without a Looper" Exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, realm, rx-java

I have the following code, based off the documentation provided by Realm (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#rxjava)

```
public Observable<Foo> getFooById(String id) {

    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

    return realm.where(Foo.class)
            .equalTo("id", id)
            .findFirstAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .filter(this::filterResult);
}
```

This works in App as expected however when it comes to testing things become a little more tricky. I have the following test (stripped down to keep it simple) :

```
@Test
public void testRealmExample() {

    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .name("test.realm")
            .inMemory()
            .build();

    DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(config);

    TestSubscriber<Foo> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    dataManager.getFoo("").observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(testSubscriber);
    testSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
}
```

When the test is executed the following error occurs `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Your Realm is opened from a thread without a Looper. Async queries need a Handler to send results of your query`.

To counter this I read on the [Realm GitHub page](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/RxJavaTests.java) that they use an annotation `@UiThreadTest` to force the test to run on the UI thread, which from my understanding is a looper thread, therefore this should solve my problem. I added:

```
@Rule
public final UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();
```

and changed my test to include the annotation

```
@Test
@UiThreadTest
public void testRealmExample() { ...}
```

This still yields the same exception. Does anyone know why and a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `@UiThreadTest` doesn't actually put you on a working Looper thread, just on a Thread with access to UI elements. I must confess I haven't really looked into the details on why there is that difference. We are using a custom rule for Looper threads instead (which also cleans up our Realm instances). You can see it here and maybe use that as inspiration:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/rule/RunInLooperThread.java

Comment: Thanks for this! How do these tests pass in that case? Especially `findFirstAsync_emittedOnSubscribe ` as this is nearly identical to what i am doing. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/RxJavaTests.java

Comment: I have a suspicion that `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread` is actually not valid during unit tests. You can see in our tests we just observe on the default thread. Just a guess though, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think for now I am going to expand our Realm test rig App to run the equivalent of the tests I wanted to run. It would be easier and we still gain coverage. Realm's great but Unit Testing seems quite difficult, is this something on the roadmap?

Comment: Yes, right now we are looking into adding Robolectric support, and hopefully standard JUnit4 support down the line.

Comment: Just one thing: Substitute your schedulers in tests. See the posts by [Alexis Mas](http://alexismas.com/blog/2015/05/20/unit-testing-rxjava/) and [Federico Paolinelli](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2015/09/13/testing-rxjava-observables-subscriptions/) for how to do that.

Comment: Been looking for this answer all day. Thanks!